# How to shutdown my Jenkins safely?

Tags: jenkins

I run Jenkins in its own container. I use the command "nohup java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=8443".

How do I shut it down safely? Right now, I use the kill command to kill the process.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "safely". Do you mean that Jenkins would not shut down if it is in the middle of a build? Or merely that Jenkins shuts down cleanly without corrupting any config files?

Comment: both i.e not shutdown if its in the middle of a build and shut down cleanly

Comment: [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698419/how-can-a-jenkins-user-authentication-details-be-passed-to-a-script-which-uses)

Comment: Missing in all the answers on this page is `http://yourjenkins/quietDown`. This will ensure new builds don't run but keeps existing builds running. Also, when you bring up your Jenkins, you might want to flush the queue: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/clearBuildQueue.groovy

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, kill should be fine if you're running Jenkins with the built-in Winstone container.  [This Jenkins Wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) has some tips on how to set up control scripts for Jenkins.

Answer (score 131):

Use `http://[jenkins-server]/exit`

[This page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) shows how to use URL commands.

Comment: URL Options
http://[jenkins-server]/[command]
where [command] can be

exit shutdown jenkins
restart restart jenkins
reload to reload the configuration

Answer (score 65):

If you would like to stop jenkins and all its services on the server using Linux console (e.g. Ubuntu), run:

```
service jenkins start/stop/restart
```

This is useful when you need to make an image/volume snapshot and you want all services to stop writing to the disk/volume.

Comment: This answer assumes that Jenkins was installed using the Debian or RPM package, which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 31):

1. jenkinsUrl/safeRestart - Let you to wait for running JOBS to get complete and do a RESTART.
2. jenkinsUrl/restart - Do a restart immediately without waiting for the jobs which are running currently.
3. jenkinsUrl/exit - It stops/shutdown the JENKINS services
4. jenkinsUrl/reload - To reload the configuration changes.

Comment: Why the heck did they make it safeRestart and then safe-shutdown instead of safeShutdown? It's inconsistencies like these that drive a dev up the wall (and force us to look everything up on StackOverflow). </rant>
FYI safe-shutdown no longer works.

Answer (score 25):

The full list of commands is available at `http://your-jenkins/cli`

The command for a clean shutdown is `http://your-jenkins/safe-shutdown`

You may also want to use `http://your-jenkins/safe-restart`

Comment: /safe-restart does not work with my Jenkins installation. Does it come with a particular version or plugin?

Comment: Apparently with Jenkins version 1.5+ there is a /safeRestart supported URL.

Comment: To safely (e.g. wait for jobs) restart - `http://your-jenkins/safeRestart`.  To safely exit - `http://your-jenkins/safeExit`

Answer (score 8):

You can kill Jenkins safely. It will catch SIGTERM and SIGINT and perform an orderly shutdown. However, if Jenkins was in the middle of building something, it will abort the builds and they will show up gray in the status display.

If you want to avoid this, you must put Jenkins into shutdown mode to prevent it from starting new builds and wait until currently running builds are done before killing Jenkins.

You can also use the Jenkins command line interface and tell Jenkins to safe-shutdown, which does the same. You can find more info on Jenkins cli at http://YOURJENKINS/cli

Comment: ...and it seems that if it fails to respond to SIGINT and SIGTERM, then perhaps SIGKILL is justified (although probably not 'safe').

Answer (score 2):

Create a Jenkins Job that runs on Master:

```
java -jar "%JENKINS_HOME%/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar" -s "%JENKINS_URL%" safe-restart
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also look in the init script area (e.g. centos vi /etc/init.d/jenkins ) for details on how the service is actually started and stopped.

Answer (score 1):

**Immediately shuts down Jenkins server.**

In Windows `CMD.exe`, Go to folder where `jenkins-cli.jar` file is located.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF`

**Use Command to Safely Shutdown**

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 safe-shutdown --username "YourUsername" 
--password "YourPassword"
```

The full list of commands is available at http://localhost:8080/cli

Credits to [Francisco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13527164/2218697) post for `cli` commands.

Reference:

[1.](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21086)

Hope helps someone.

Comment: I do not find this folder on Windows 10 Home. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`

Comment: @likejudo, then go to any other `C:\Program Files`  folder on Windows 10 were `Jenkins` is installed.