# How can a Jenkins user authentication details be "passed" to a script which uses Jenkins API to create jobs?

Tags: api, curl, jenkins, token

I have a script that delete and re-create jobs through curl HTTP-calls and I want to get rid of any hard-coded "username:password".
E.g. `curl -X POST $url --user username:password`

Considerations:

- **Jenkins CLI** (probably not an option). 
  One should be able to achieve the same with the CLI as with Jenkins API (creating jobs etc) but as far as I understand Jenkins CLI is not a good alternative for me since jobs created with will only appear in Jenkins after restarting or a "Reload Configuration from Disk", and that would cancel any other running jobs.
- **API token**. Can't find out how to get the user token and then pass it
  as a parameter to the script, but that may be a solution..

Answer (score 97):

Try this way: (for example delete the job)

```
curl --silent --show-error http://<username>:<api-token>@<jenkins-server>/job/<job-name>/doDelete
```

The api-token can be obtained from `http://<jenkins-server>/user/<username>/configure`.

Comment: As an administrator, how do I get an API token for a user other than myself, without logging in as them?  When I visit the page you cite, all I see is that "Token is hidden".

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Did you manage to find a solution to your question ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035319/as-a-jenkins-administrator-how-do-i-get-a-users-api-token-without-logging-in-a

Answer (score 31):

This worked for me:

```
curl -u $username:$api_token -FSubmit=Build 'http://<jenkins-server>/job/<job-name>/buildWithParameters?environment='
```

API token can be obtained from Jenkins user configuration.

Comment: As an administrator, how do I get an API token for a user other than myself, without logging in as them? When I visit the Jenkins user configuration, all I see is that "Token is hidden".

Comment: I'm using Active Directory for authentication and it doesn't seem to let me log in as local users to see the token.

Comment: This doesn't work with Google Authentication either.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035319/as-a-jenkins-administrator-how-do-i-get-a-users-api-token-without-logging-in-a

Answer (score 9):

- With Jenkins CLI you do not have to reload everything - you just can load the job (*update-job* command). You can't use tokens with CLI, AFAIK - you have to use password or password file.
- Token name for user can be obtained via `http://<jenkins-server>/user/<username>/configure` - push on 'Show API token' button.
- Here's a [link on how to use API tokens](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) (it uses `wget`, but `curl` is very similar).

Comment: Thank you,
Knowing that CLI would work withouth reloading conf from disk is good, but then I'd have to make a new script.

The use of token would be better i think, but i don't see from example on the linked page how I could pass the api-token for the user to the variable TOKEN in for example `...ob/build?token=TOKEN`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Will [this help](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)? (Look in *Submitting Jobs* section).

Comment: As an administrator, how do I get an API token for a user other than myself, without logging in as them?  When I visit the page you cite, all I see is that "Token is hidden".

Answer (score 7):

I needed to explicitly add POST in the CURL command:

```
curl -X POST http://<user>:<token>@<server>/safeRestart
```

I also have the [SafeRestart Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SafeRestart+Plugin) installed, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a script to automate creation of jobs using the Jenkins API, you can use one of the API clients to do that. A ruby client for Jenkins is available at https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client

```
gem install jenkins_api_client

require "rubygems"
require "jenkins_api_client"

# Initialize the client by passing in the server information
# and credentials to communicate with the server
client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(
  :server_ip => "127.0.0.1",
  :username => "awesomeuser",
  :password => "awesomepassword"
)

# The following block will create 10 jobs in Jenkins
# test_job_0, test_job_1, test_job_2, ...
10.times do |num|
  client.job.create_freestyle(:name => "test_job_#{num}")
end

# The jobs in Jenkins can be listed using
client.job.list_all
```

The API client can be used to perform a lot of operations.

Answer (score 1):

API token is the same as password from API point of view, see source code [uses token in place of passwords for the API](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/security/ApiTokenFilter.java#L49).

See related answer from @coffeebreaks in my question [python-jenkins or jenkinsapi for jenkins remote access API in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074521/python-jenkins-or-jenkinsapi-for-jenkins-remote-access-api-in-python)

Others is described in doc to use http basic authentication model

Answer (score 0):

In order to use API tokens, users will have to obtain their own tokens, each from `https://<jenkins-server>/me/configure` or `https://<jenkins-server>/user/<user-name>/configure`. It is up to you, as the author of the script, to determine how users supply the token to the script. For example, in a Bourne Shell script running interactively inside a Git repository, where `.gitignore` contains `/.jenkins_api_token`, you might do something like:

```sh
api_token_file="$(git rev-parse --show-cdup).jenkins_api_token"
api_token=$(cat "$api_token_file" || true)
if [ -z "$api_token" ]; then
    echo
    echo "Obtain your API token from $JENKINS_URL/user/$user/configure"
    echo "After entering here, it will be saved in $api_token_file; keep it safe!"
    read -p "Enter your Jenkins API token: " api_token
    echo $api_token > "$api_token_file"
fi
curl -u $user:$api_token $JENKINS_URL/someCommand
```