# python-jenkins or jenkinsapi for jenkins remote access API in python

Tags: python, jenkins

There are two python packages exist for jenkins remote access API, I need help to compare those two packages, so I can judge which to use.

- python-jenkins http://pythonhosted.org/python-jenkins/
- JenkinsAPI: http://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/

So far for my thoughts:

- python-jenkins is quite simple interface and is part of new Ubuntu release, which means easy to use, mature enough for general usage.
- JenkinsAPI is mentioned in [Jenkins official document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API), it looks new, but it is more connected with jenkins API development as well.

What I needed so far:

- https access and simple authentication (token inside jenkins) : document is not clear both
- get list of installed plugins (possible for those packages ?)
- get list of jobs
- get config xml from job
- .. may needed for other exposed remote Access API later

I want to stick with python API in high level module, if possible, avoid to use python-requests module

Any more ideas ?

**EDIT** refine the questions after the comments below

Comment: Have you tried them yourself? What problems did you encounter? What problem are you trying to solve here, what would you require the library to do?

Comment: @martijn: thanks for remind, I updated with my analyse.

Comment: You are not telling us what you want to do apart from using the secure tokens. What do you intend to script ? Do you absolutely need python? For example, there are other ways to access jenkins, for example the CLI: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI which works with ssh keys.

Comment: coffeebreaks: thanks. I just want to have general comparison, also I want to stick with python for a moment.

Comment: In _python-jenkins_, it is not possible to include a file as a parameter to build a job, while _jenkinsapi_ supports it.

Comment: Both of these libraries seem to lock you into their way of doing it. I looked at both and rejected both. You may be better off using the REST API directly with a decent url fetch library (e.g., urllib3, requests, etc.).

Comment: in year 2021 the better option seems for me to be api4jenkins https://pypi.org/project/api4jenkins/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given that both seem to have more or less the basic features and that JenkinsAPI is

1. mentioned by the official documentation
2. more active ([jenkins-python history](https://code.launchpad.net/~python-jenkins-developers/python-jenkins/trunk) vs [jenkinsapi history](https://github.com/salimfadhley/jenkinsapi/commits/master))

I would go for jenkinsapi.

As for token support, given [the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients), the fact that the code [uses token in place of passwords for the API](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/security/ApiTokenFilter.java#L49) and [is backward compatible with basic auth](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/security/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java?source=cc#L138), I would say that any client that supports passwords will support tokens.

Comment: like the history link and the source codes on how to handle token/passwd, which makes me clear

Comment: @coffeebreaks Thanks a ton! The backward compatible with basic auth saved a ton of time!!

Comment: jenkins-python seemed to start getting more features and is hosted by openstack.org https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/python-jenkins/

Comment: jenkins-python has a lot more features making its choice a no-brainer for any serious jenkins automation

Comment: Jenkinsapi just doesn't work  for big instances: https://github.com/pycontribs/jenkinsapi/issues/525

Comment: it's weird the python one recommends ast.literal_eval rather than json.loads :/