# Jenkins: mark node as offline gets 403 Forbidden

Tags: jenkins

Maybe it's a dumb way to do so, but I'm trying to figure out the best one. Using JenkinsAPI from python, I'm running a job on a specific node using

```
job.invoke("jobToken",False,False,3,5,{"NODE": node_name}).
```

The job itself is trying to mark the node as temporary offline. What the job runs is specified in the Build -> Execute Shell -> Command in the job configuration screen.
Using

```
wget "http://jenkins/computer/${NODE}/toggleOffline?offlineMessage=Taken_down"
```

I get a 403 Forbidden error on the console output.
Using

```
curl "http://jenkins/computer/${NODE}/toggleOffline?offlineMessage=Taken_down"
```

I get html response saying "Authentication required". (on the console output as well).
So my question is how to mark a node as offline, from within the job.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to add username and password

```
curl -X POST "http://jenkins/computer/${NODE}/toggleOffline?offlineMessage=Taken_down" --user username:password
```

I saw this at:
[How can a Jenkins user authentication details be "passed" to a script which uses Jenkins API to create jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698419/how-can-a-jenkins-user-authentication-details-be-passed-to-a-script-which-uses)

Comment: Thanks, this works well, but I do want to get rid off this "hardcoding" as the guy in your link asked. The job in running on node X and I want to mark offline node X itself. I though no special credentials are needed for that. I could use our "root" user API Token, but this doesn't seem as a good option ("publishing" this token in our jobs).

Comment: One way is to use `.netrc` which can be kept mode `600` to protect credentials