# Triggering builds remotely in Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins

I had tried to trigger my Jenkins project by using this URL in my commit hook

```
curl http://jenkins_server/job/job_name/build?token=TOKEN
```

and is not getting triggered. But when i type this URL in my web browser, it triggers my build.

When i tried in my command prompt, I got an error

> Error 404
>
> ## Status Co
>   de: 404
>
> Exception: 
> Stacktrace:
>
> ```
> (none)
> ```
>
> *Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.
>   10 at Tue Apr 22 16:57:38 CEST 2014*

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as Electrawn suggested, verify that the server where the commit hook is running can actually reach Jenkins DNS. A simple ping or curl to the root address (i.e. `http://jenkins_server`) would suffice

Secondly, if your Jenkins does not allow anonymous read access and build triggering (and most installations won't) your issue is that your `curl` call is not logged in. In your browser, try logging out from Jenkins and then going to the same URL. Does that work? Probably not.

To pass login credentials with curl, have a read here: **[How can a Jenkins user authentication details be "passed" to a script which uses Jenkins API to create jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698419/how-can-a-jenkins-user-authentication-details-be-passed-to-a-script-which-uses)**

More succinct answer **[here](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Accessing+Jenkins+using+HTTP+Basic+Authentication)**

Answer (score 0):

Does the server running curl have a hosts/DNS entry back to jenkins_server?