# How to select a node name as a parameter in jenkins using a selection list of some sort

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-plugins

I need to know if there is a plugin of some sort that you can select a node from a jenkins job and use that node name as a parameter to be passed to a Windows batch command

I have played with the Configuration Matrix using an Elastic-Axis or Slaves (Screenshot below where you can tick the names) plugins

[image]

But these all go and execute the Windows batch command on that selected node.

I don't want to execute it on that server but rather on the main node and only pass the value of the slave/label to the windows batch command.

I were able to do it as described here but that involves 2 jobs and a groovy scripts to interrogate the slaves/nodes config. Write it to a properties file and pass the properties file to the next job.

[Jenkins: How to get node name from label to use as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341081/jenkins-how-to-get-node-name-from-label-to-use-as-a-parameter)

I need to do about 30 jobs of these and hence would like to try to do all in one job - if I used my solution in the link above, 30 jobs would double in 60 jobs and maintenance would be kind of a nightmare.

I also would not like to have a string parameter and hard code the name of the slave/node as that will not ensure the use of only the available slaves/nodes but any server name can be entered and that would can be a problem where someone can mistype a server name for example pointing to a Production server instead of a test server.

Answer (score 3):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin
After installing this plugin you will have an option to add a `Node` parameter to Jenkins job. It will have a list of all slaves available on current master.

Comment: Not what I want. This allows you to create a node parameter. But if I run a Job it will also execute on that node. I still want to the job to be executed on the master but I need to know the name of the selected node.

Comment: You would need some kind of a node scheduler plugin that actually doesn't utilize any of the nodes from Jenkins point of view, is that correct?

Comment: I have a MVN SOAP project that executes tests on a server. The SOAP project needs to know what server to run on. Hence I have the ability to target our DEV TEST and LIVE environment.

What I am trying to do is just to have some selection list a project can use to choose from the node list. (we already make use of nodes for deployments). 

If I can get the node (or server name) into a variable I can pass this to the MVN project which will pass it to the SOAP project to execute on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the active choice parameter plugin
https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/
with a little groovy script to list node names in a parameter selection box.

[image]