# Authentication Required while uploading file from Jenkins Workspace

Tags: svn, jenkins, version-control, continuous-integration, auto-build

I am trying to get the Changelog to one file and save into the workspace and uploading the same file to hockeyapp from workspace as Postbuild Action using the below commands.

**Changelog=$(curl "${BUILD_URL}api/xml?wrapper=changes&xpath=//changeSet//item//msg" | sed -e "s/</msg>//g; s//\`echo -e '\r'`/g; s/</*changes>//g" )
echo -e "$Changelog" > "${WORKSPACE}/"Changelog-${BUILD_NUMBER}.html**

The error in console log shows as below.

```
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn'\''t): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

Can anyone please suggest how we can make it work.

Comment: It seems that your Jenkins server don't allow anonymous access. So you have to login to get the changelog. Jenkins is running on Windows or Linux? (I may have one solution for Linux, waiting for your answer)

Comment: I am already logined as  Admin, My Jenkins was running on Mac OS X . Thanks

Comment: Curl is trying to get the changelog with an anonymous access. You should go in the Jenkins config and allow a read access for the anonymous user (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup, section Matrix-based Security).

Comment: Thanks for Info, Do you have any idea to pass Admin/Specific user details in curl to access Changelog instead of anonymous user .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698419/how-can-a-jenkins-user-authentication-details-be-passed-to-a-script-which-uses