# As a Jenkins administrator, how do I get a user's API token without logging in as them?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

As an administrator, how do I get an API token for a user other than myself, without logging in as them? When I visit the user configuration page, all I see is that "Token is hidden", and I cannot change it either.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could get it. Think of the mayhem it would cause if an admin could just grab anyone's token, use it to totally destroy a bunch of stuff, and have that user blamed for it because it was all done under the user's token.

Comment: But an admin can cause mayhem in much simpler ways, right?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060508-22/?p=31283

Comment: But using another user's token to do so would result in that user being blamed, without being able to trace the admin's involvement. *I want Patrick fired, so I'll use his token and do ....., and it will be clear to everyone that he did it.* is a little different. It's the same reason a Windows admin can not read a user's current password.

Comment: So this makes it difficult to set up a system account that can't log in but is used only for API calls.

Comment: Why? You set up the system account, and then you log in as that system account user to call the API functions.

Comment: "you log in as that system account user".  For better security, we might want to make that account non-loginable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a Jenkins System Property, jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty.showTokenToAdmins .  You need access to the master/OC process startup to change it.

Documented at the bottom of https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

(We are going to do our best to leave this at false.)

Comment: I guess after seeing this answer, I have to be surprised. :-)