# Update Jenkins which is currently running as a Linux service

Tags: jenkins

How do I update jenkins from a existing jenkins install running as a Linux service without loosing any jobs or config?

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Automated+Upgrade

Comment: `without loosing any jobs or config` You can [shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238604/how-to-shutdown-my-jenkins-safely) Jenkins before update.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, you need to find where your jenkins.war file is installed:

```
locate jenkins.war
```

On my Centos machine, it's here: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war

Stop the Jenkins service:

```
service jenkins stop
```

Next, you can backup the existing jenkins.war file:

```
cd /usr/share/jenkins
mv jenkins.war jenkins-1.586.war
```

And to finish, please copy the new jenkins.war file in the same location:

```
cp jenkins.war /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Restart the Jenkins service:

```
service jenkins start
```

It should work and you should retrieve your Jenkins configuration (which is stored in your Jenkins home folder).

Comment: Followed instructions but when issueing service jenkins status I get
jenkins dead but pid file exists

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/cache/jenkins/war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (Permission denied)

Chowning directory to the user jenkins run's as fixed the problem

Comment: When you copied the war file, which Linux account did you use? Jenkins, root or another account?
After fixing the permission on your folder, can you confirm that the Jenkins upgrade is OK and that you didn't loose your Jenkins config?

Comment: No config lost, I used the root user.

Comment: OK perfect, may be you can consider my first answer as useful ;)

Comment: I followed these directions but couldn't get Jenkins to start, until I realized it had been installed as an rpm, and all I needed was "sudo yum update jenkins"